# Does install4J provide jar encryption?

Tags: install4j

I am using install4J and I cannot figure out whether I can use it to encrypt the jar or not. Nothing mentioned in the documentation.
Any ideas? is there an alternative?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, install4j does not offer any kind of encryption.